# Cloudformation init - install docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use AWS `Cloudformation init` to install docker and docker-compose on some ec2 instances.

> Before trying this I have just used user data successfully

I am using this template

```yaml
# Use public Systems Manager Parameter
Parameters:
    LatestAmiId:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: '/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2'
Resources:
    host1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
        AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
            configSets:
                ec2_bootstrap:
                    - install_docker
                    # - install_compose
            install_docker:
                packages:
                    yum:
                        docker: []
                services:
                    sysvinit:
                        docker:
                            enabled: "true"
                            ensureRunning: "true"
                commands:
                    docker_for_ec2_user:
                        command: usermod -G docker ec2-user
            # install_compose:
            #     commands:
            #         compose_for_ec2_user:
            #             command: 
            #               - curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.20.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
            #               - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
            #               - ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
    CreationPolicy:
        ResourceSignal:
            Timeout: PT5M
    Properties:
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        KeyName: NVirginia
        # Note we use the pseudo parameter AWS::Region
        ImageId: !Ref LatestAmiId
        AvailabilityZone: !Sub ${AWS::Region}a
        Tags: 
        - Key: "Name"
        Value: "host1"
        SecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt SSHSecurityGroupStack.Outputs.SSHGroupId
        UserData:
        "Fn::Base64":
            !Sub |

        #!/bin/bash -xe
        # Get the latest CloudFormation package
        yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
        # Start cfn-init
        /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ${AWS::StackId} -r host1 --region ${AWS::Region}a || error_exit 'Failed to run cfn-init'
        # Start up the cfn-hup daemon to listen for changes to the EC2 instance metadata
        /opt/aws/bin/cfn-hup || error_exit 'Failed to start cfn-hup'
        # All done so signal success
        /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource host1 --region ${AWS::Region}a
            
            ## change the hostname
            sudo hostname host1
            ## restart docker
            sudo service docker restart
    

    SSHSecurityGroupStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
        TemplateURL: https://cloudformation-bruvio-templates.s3.amazonaws.com/ssh-security-group.yaml
        TimeoutInMinutes: 5
```

the template is supposed to create a security group with a couple of ports open and then an ec2 instance and use init to install docker and docker-compose

I actually copied the init part from  [this post](https://hands-on.cloud/cloudformation-tutorial-how-to-automate-ec2-instance-in-5-mins/)

The stack fails when trying to create the instance as does not receive the success signal

I wonder what is wrong?

Comment: You're not calling cfn-init or cfn-signal from your user data. https://serverfault.com/a/916038/105633

Comment: I have added inside user data the calls! still not working

Comment: Don't use `set -e` for the user data because that will cause the script to exit on failure before cfn-signal is called.

Comment: You can login to the instance before the signal timeout and view the cloud-init logs.

Comment: Your script also contains references to a function called `error_exit` which you have not defined.

Comment: `/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ${AWS::StackId} -r host1 --region ${AWS::Region}a || error_exit 'Failed to run cfn-init'`
  and this `/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource host1 --region ${AWS::Region}a`  this is a typo extra character `a` at the end, unless you didnt noticed it yet.  Syntactically CFN seems right, run it throug the linter you will figure it out. Plus  loose `-xe` option in the shebang.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are **many issues** in your template. Some of them are:

- missing `-configsets`
- wrong region `${AWS::StackId}`
- no `hup` defined
- indentation problems
- missing `error_exit`

I **fixed** all of them, and it should work now:

```yaml
# Use public Systems Manager Parameter
Parameters:
  LatestAmiId:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: '/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2'
Resources:
  host1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
        AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
            configSets:
                ec2_bootstrap:
                    - install_docker
                    # - install_compose
            install_docker:
                packages:
                    yum:
                        docker: []
                services:
                    sysvinit:
                        docker:
                            enabled: "true"
                            ensureRunning: "true"
                commands:
                    docker_for_ec2_user:
                        command: usermod -G docker ec2-user
            # install_compose:
            #     commands:
            #         compose_for_ec2_user:
            #             command: 
            #               - curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.20.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
            #               - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
            #               - ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
    CreationPolicy:
        ResourceSignal:
            Timeout: PT5M
    Properties:
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        KeyName: NVirginia
        # Note we use the pseudo parameter AWS::Region
        ImageId: !Ref LatestAmiId
        AvailabilityZone: !Sub ${AWS::Region}a
        Tags: 
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "host1"
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !GetAtt SSHSecurityGroupStack.Outputs.SSHGroupId
        UserData:
          "Fn::Base64":
              !Sub |
                #!/bin/bash -xe
                # Get the latest CloudFormation package
                yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
                # Start cfn-init
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ${AWS::StackId} -r host1 --configsets ec2_bootstrap --region ${AWS::Region} 
                # All done so signal success
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource host1 --region ${AWS::Region}
```

Comment: thanks! your template work.. I also fixed the missing parts (I think). I will update the code used.

Comment: @bruvio No problem. Glad it worked out:-)

Answer (score 0):

this is the code I used. I applied @marcin advice.

I create 3 instances in this case (as I want to do some tests with a docker swarm).. only thing is that I also try to install compose. cloudformation does not fail but compose is not installed

```
    # Use public Systems Manager Parameter
Parameters:
  LatestAmiId:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: '/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2'
Resources:
  host1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
        AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
            configSets:
                ec2_bootstrap:
                    - install_docker
                    - install_compose
            install_docker:
                packages:
                    yum:
                        docker: []
                services:
                    sysvinit:
                        docker:
                            enabled: "true"
                            ensureRunning: "true"
                files:
                  "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf":
                    content: !Sub |
                      [main]
                      stack=${AWS::StackId}
                      region=${AWS::Region}
                    mode: "000400"
                    owner: "root"
                    group: "root"
                  "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf":
                    content: !Sub |
                        [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
                        triggers=post.update
                        path=Resources.host1.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
                        action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource host1 --region ${AWS::Region}
                    mode: "000400"
                    owner: "root"
                    group: "root"

                commands:
                    docker_for_ec2_user:
                        command: usermod -G docker ec2-user
            install_compose:
                commands:
                    compose_for_ec2_user1:
                        command: 
                          curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.20.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
                    compose_for_ec2_user2:
                        command:
                          chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
                          
                    compose_for_ec2_user3:
                        command:
                          ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose

    CreationPolicy:
        ResourceSignal:
            Timeout: PT2M
    Properties:
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        KeyName: NVirginia
        # Note we use the pseudo parameter AWS::Region
        ImageId: !Ref LatestAmiId
        AvailabilityZone: !Sub ${AWS::Region}a
        Tags: 
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "host1"
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !GetAtt SSHSecurityGroupStack.Outputs.SSHGroupId
        UserData:
          "Fn::Base64":
              !Sub |
                #!/bin/bash -xe
                # Get the latest CloudFormation package
                yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
                # Start cfn-init
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ${AWS::StackId} -r host1 --configsets ec2_bootstrap --region ${AWS::Region} 
                # All done so signal success
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource host1 --region ${AWS::Region}      
                # Start up the cfn-hup daemon to listen for changes to the EC2 instance metadata
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-hup              

  host2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
        AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
            configSets:
                ec2_bootstrap:
                    - install_docker
                    - install_compose
            install_docker:
                packages:
                    yum:
                        docker: []
                services:
                    sysvinit:
                        docker:
                            enabled: "true"
                            ensureRunning: "true"
                files:
                  "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf":
                    content: !Sub |
                      [main]
                      stack=${AWS::StackId}
                      region=${AWS::Region}
                    mode: "000400"
                    owner: "root"
                    group: "root"
                  "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf":
                    content: !Sub |
                        [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
                        triggers=post.update
                        path=Resources.host2.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
                        action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource host2 --region ${AWS::Region}
                    mode: "000400"
                    owner: "root"
                    group: "root"

                commands:
                    docker_for_ec2_user:
                        command: usermod -G docker ec2-user
            install_compose:
                commands:
                    compose_for_ec2_user1:
                        command: 
                          curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.20.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
                    compose_for_ec2_user2:
                        command:
                          chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
                          
                    compose_for_ec2_user3:
                        command:
                          ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose

    CreationPolicy:
        ResourceSignal:
            Timeout: PT2M
    Properties:
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        KeyName: NVirginia
        # Note we use the pseudo parameter AWS::Region
        ImageId: !Ref LatestAmiId
        AvailabilityZone: !Sub ${AWS::Region}a
        Tags: 
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "host2"
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !GetAtt SSHSecurityGroupStack.Outputs.SSHGroupId
        UserData:
          "Fn::Base64":
              !Sub |
                #!/bin/bash -xe
                # Get the latest CloudFormation package
                yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
                # Start cfn-init
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ${AWS::StackId} -r host2 --configsets ec2_bootstrap --region ${AWS::Region} 
                # All done so signal success
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource host2 --region ${AWS::Region}      
                # Start up the cfn-hup daemon to listen for changes to the EC2 instance metadata
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-hup


  host3:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Metadata:
        AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
            configSets:
                ec2_bootstrap:
                    - install_docker
                    - install_compose
            install_docker:
                packages:
                    yum:
                        docker: []
                services:
                    sysvinit:
                        docker:
                            enabled: "true"
                            ensureRunning: "true"
                files:
                  "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf":
                    content: !Sub |
                      [main]
                      stack=${AWS::StackId}
                      region=${AWS::Region}
                    mode: "000400"
                    owner: "root"
                    group: "root"
                  "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf":
                    content: !Sub |
                        [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
                        triggers=post.update
                        path=Resources.host3.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
                        action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource host3 --region ${AWS::Region}
                    mode: "000400"
                    owner: "root"
                    group: "root"

                commands:
                    docker_for_ec2_user:
                        command: usermod -G docker ec2-user
            install_compose:
                    compose_for_ec2_user1:
                        command: 
                          curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.20.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
                    compose_for_ec2_user2:
                        command:
                          chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
                          
                    compose_for_ec2_user3:
                        command:
                          ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose

    CreationPolicy:
        ResourceSignal:
            Timeout: PT2M
    Properties:
        InstanceType: t2.micro
        KeyName: NVirginia
        # Note we use the pseudo parameter AWS::Region
        ImageId: !Ref LatestAmiId
        AvailabilityZone: !Sub ${AWS::Region}a
        Tags: 
        - Key: "Name"
          Value: "host3"
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !GetAtt SSHSecurityGroupStack.Outputs.SSHGroupId
        UserData:
          "Fn::Base64":
              !Sub |
                #!/bin/bash -xe
                # Get the latest CloudFormation package
                yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
                # Start cfn-init
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ${AWS::StackId} -r host3 --configsets ec2_bootstrap --region ${AWS::Region} 
                # All done so signal success
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackId} --resource host3 --region ${AWS::Region}      
                # Start up the cfn-hup daemon to listen for changes to the EC2 instance metadata
                /opt/aws/bin/cfn-hup              

  SSHSecurityGroupStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: https://cloudformation-bruvio-templates.s3.amazonaws.com/ssh-security-group.yaml
      TimeoutInMinutes: 5
```